# JQM 1.3 changePage 'role dialog' fails in Chrome

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to change to a different page on start up and I want it to be a dialog.
**This works in 1.2 and works with IE and FireFox in 1.3.**
Chrome displays the dialog then immediately reverts to the first page.
If I remove the "role: dialog" it works with everyone.  I've tried a hidden hyperlink that I force a click on ... same result.  Chrome (latest version) reverts to page1.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a simplified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stocksp/P4ZWj/3/

```
    div data-role="page" id="page1">
       <div data-role="content">
           <h6>page one content</h6>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 class="title">My DIALOG </h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            Dialog Content
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).delegate("#page1", "pageinit", function () {
            $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick workaround til this is fixed: wrap the changePage method in a setTimeout...

```
$(document).delegate("#page1", "pageinit", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });
    }, 100);
});
```